# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/dev/urandom' , although I open the file only once

Tags: python, paramiko, ulimit

I am opening a file in append mode once and then writing to it in a loop
But I hit this error after a while and my script dies.

This is what I run

> python monitor_free.py ucs107-cip-m 86400 &

My script goes like this

```
import sys
import time

from sp_cluster import SpCluster

clusterip = sys.argv[1]
timeout = int(sys.argv[2])
cl = SpCluster(str(clusterip))
x = cl.stctlvms
f = open("free_stat.txt", "a")
start_time = time.time()
elapsed = 0
seperator = "*" * 79
while(elapsed < timeout):
    for vm in x:
        text, _, _ = vm.ssh_cmd("free -ko -bm")
        dates, _, _ = vm.ssh_cmd("date")

        f.write(seperator)
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(str(vm.fqdn))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(str(dates))
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(str(text))
        f.write("\n")
        time.sleep(10)
        elapsed = time.time() - start_time
```

My understanding was that there should only be one fd open the whole time....but seems like its wrong... anyone knows whats happening?

Error is thrown by paramiko

```
ERROR:   Unknown exception: [Errno 24] Too many open files:   '/dev/urandom'
ERROR:   Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR:     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-  packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1719, in run
ERROR:     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1909, in _send_kex_init
ERROR:   OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/dev/urandom'
```

Comment: What are the ** marking on the line where you open the file?

Comment: How many times have you run this script? It could be leaving a file open each time. It's hard to say without seeing what you are doing with Paramiko.

Comment: i may have run this 5-10  times max, but i kill the process before i restart

Comment: It's not necessarily a limit on number of times *that particular* file is open -- can just as easily be a limit on the file descriptor table size. Anyhow, when this is happening (before the interpreter exits -- consider using `python -i` to prevent such), use `lsof` or `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` to see which and how many FDs are open.

Comment: BTW, your indentation is definitely wrong -- this is showing no indent after `for vm in x:`

Comment: ...and every network socket eats a file descriptor, so it's under no circumstances only one.

Comment: That was the case, we weren't closing the connections in our SSH library.. thanks Charles